# needle in the hays - How to find exact file from recycle bin

Tags: recycle-bin

The recycle bin for this given site collection (Projects) contains over 14,000 items. I need to find few documents that has following metadata. How do I do that? It seems I can't add additional metadata to the recycle bin view.

Customer Name = "Proctor & Gamble"
Customer Region = "NW"

Answer (score 0):

You can try SPRecycleBinQuery in Powershell, but that won't give you the option in UI.. so I suggest, if you want to restore this item you do it from Powershell too..

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

#Get the Site collection
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sharepoint.company.com")

#Create new object for SPRecycleBinQuery
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinQuery

#$query.ItemState = "FirstStageRecycleBin"
$query.ItemState = "SecondStageRecycleBin"

#How many Rows to be returned
$query.RowLimit = 100

#Call GetRecycleBinItems to Search Inside SharePoint Recycle Bin
$DeletedItemsColl = $site.GetRecycleBinItems($query)

#Filter Result
$Result= $DeletedItemsColl | where  {$_.Title -match ".txt"}

#Write output
$Result | foreach-object {
    (Write-Host "Found Item:" $_.Title)
    (write-host "Created by:" $_.AuthorName)
    (write-host "Deleted by:" $_.DeletedByName)
    (write-host  "Deleted Date:"$_.DeletedDate)
  (write-host  "File Size(Bytes):" $_.Size)
  (write-host  "Original Location:" $_.DirName)
  (write-host "Web:" $_.web.URL)
 (Write-Host "------------------------------------")
  }
```

Checkout this post:

[Search SharePoint Recycle bin with SPRecycleBinQuery](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/02/search-recycle-bin-sprecyclebinquery.html)

Comment: Is there a way to get this code in jQuery and this may give UI output? http://allaboutmoss.com/2011/11/04/recycle-bin-search-webpart-for-sharepoint/

Comment: Possible, try it out..